# Using Stream to instantiate new objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In `java8`, I got a Set of String:

```
final Set<String> nameSet = this.getNames();
```

And I want to get a list of `People`, setting the name of `People` based on the String from the `Set`.
However, `People` class do not have a constructor like `new People(name)`, it can only be implemented by using `setName` method.

In old way, I can do something like:

```
    List<People> peoples = new ArrayList<People>();
    for(String name: nameSet){
        People people = new People();
        people.setName(name);
        peoples.add(people);
    }
```

How could I use `Stream` to convert this?

Comment: Class names should generally be singular (unless each instance represents a collection of items). You should probably name your class `Person`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If possible, it may be worth considering adding a `People` constructor that takes a name.  Then you could do this:

```
List<People> peoples = nameSet.stream()
  .map(People::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you can't add a constructor, you can either do it like this:

```
List<People> peoples = nameSet.stream()
  .map(name -> {
    People people = new People();
    people.setName(name);
    return people;
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or better in my opinion:

```
List<People> peoples = nameSet.stream()
  .map(name -> createPeopleFromName(name))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And elsewhere in the code have this method, perhaps in a `PeopleUtils` class:

```
public static People createPeopleFromName(String name)
{
  People people = new People();
  people.setName(name);
  return people;
}
```

Maybe also consider renaming the class `People` to `Person`.

Comment: I think `builder pattern` would be the choice. :)